# How to sort a queue in java using recursion?

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, queue

I'm trying to sort a queue of integers with recursion. I'm pretty sure I understand the logic of this thing. But I must've missed something in my code since it's not working properly. It only works for simple queues with 2 numbers only, anything other than that, it just doesn't work. Could anyone please tell me what I've missed? Thanks in advance!

```
public Queue<Integer> sort(Queue<Integer> queue) {
    Queue<Integer> cloneQueue = new Queue<Integer>(queue);
    //creating a copy of the original queue

    if (cloneQueue.size()<=1){
        return q;
        //base case
    }else{
        Queue<Integer> part1 = new Queue<Integer>();
        Queue<Integer> part2 = new Queue<Integer>();

        splitQueues(cloneQueue,part1,part2);
        //split the queue in half and put them in part1 and part2

        sort(part1);
        sort(part2);
        //recursion calls

        return mergeSortedQueues(div1,div2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  _"...it just doesn't work..."_ is insufficient, you have to be much clearer about what happens when it "doesn't work", and what steps you've taken to debug it.  To start with, step through the code in you IDE debugger.  99% of the time this will allow you to find where the code does something you weren't expecting.  Questions of the form "here's my code, please tell me what's wrong" with not much else are considered off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**
As @Jeffrey Bosboom pointed out, this is suppose to be a merge sort.

It looks when you sort part1 and part2, you are not saving the results. So change it to:

```
    part1 = sort(part1);
    part2 = sort(part2);
```

This is why it only works on a queue of 2 numbers because the two halfs are the base case.

And I assume your mergeSortedQueues function is correct, but is not shown here so that may be another source of error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the asker is trying to implement a merge sort, not the insertion sort you give here.